# What make-up techniques could be used to achieve the watercolor effect shown in this image?

Tags: makeup

I'm a filmmaker who would like to recreate a makeup effect similar to what is shown in the image below. I want to know the best techniques to turn the skin into a surface for a watercolor painting. The more details, the better.

The performer(s) with this makeup will then act and dance in a movie, so the makeup art needs to be stable under heat, sweat and movement.

The photographer is [Alexander Khokhlov](http://www.alexanderkhokhlov.com/), and the makeup artist is Valeria Kutsan.

[image: Alexander Khokhlov, photographer]

Comment: @mod Not sure if this is necessary or an improvement, but I accidentally created the tag [tag:make-up] instead of [tag:makeup]: could a mod change this?

Comment: @Joachim It's a valid spelling but less common, I merged it with makeup and made it a synonym.

Comment: @WebHead Thanks. I remember I used to write it that way, but it seems to be less common indeed.

Comment: Adding a little water to eye-shadows could give the effect probably... You can trickle it like you're supposed to do with the water colors

Answer (score 2):

I suggest a basic sunless Tanner foam ( lightest tan)dispensed mixed with some color agent that won't dye the skin permanently, like a children's bathtime paints. 
   Or, possibly use party streamers then either get wet to apply(an oil perhaps) or spray with body glitter for eye-catching gleam! 
   Good luck!